# Passing variable from Javascript to href in Codeigniter modal

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-modal

How can I pass variable value from Javascript and use it as a variable in `<a href>` bootstrap modal ? for access controller and process with the spesific / targeted ID

Answer (Trick) support by @MikO

This is `<a>`tag in bootstrap modal looks like :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" name="gotopick" id="gotopick" href="<?php echo site_url('onpartners/picking'). '/{passId}'; ?>">Pick</a>
```

Then, in your JS, you can replace that `{passID}` with the actual value of Variable with something like this :

```
$("#gotopick").attr("href", $("#gotopick").attr("href").replace('{passId}',yourvarvalue));
```

Thanks for sharing @MikO, hope your answer can help another people with same problem too here

Sharing is caring :)

Comment: can you capture the UI of your view?

Comment: `<a>` elements don't support the "value" attribute so `.val()` really won't do anything.

Comment: oh i see.. do you mean that you want to get the value in <a>. I have posted my answer, you can check it

Comment: @JamesRiady sorry for my bad, yeah you right, i want to get the value so i can pass it into my controller..give me time, i'll try your advice as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can add more attribute in your tag `<a>` like

```
<a data-id="{{ $pass_id }}" class="btn btn-primary" name="gotopick" id="gotopick" href="<?php echo site_url('onpartners/picking'). '/' . $pass_id; ?>">Pick</a>
```

So, you can get your data in your jquery like

```
var id = $('a#gotopick').data('id');
```

Comment: @MikO I accept your answer.. even you had deleted it, i've already try it, its powerful trick, thank you so much... keep inspiring us :)